# undefined variable error(PHP)

Tags: php

I got those error messages as follows:

Notice: Undefined variable: availableTest in /Users/alexhu/NetBeansProjects/menagerie/svn/trunk/apps/frontend/modules/legacy/legacy_lib/lib/classes/AppointmentTime.php on line 382

Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in /Users/alexhu/NetBeansProjects/menagerie/svn/trunk/apps/frontend/modules/legacy/legacy_lib/lib/classes/AppointmentTime.php on line 382

And my codes is as follows:

```
protected function replaceEmailTokens($emailContents) {
$additionalTestsSelected = array();

$additionalTests = $this->getAdditionalTestsSelected();
$additionalTestCostsSelected = $this->getAdditionalTestCostsSelected();

foreach($additionalTests as $availableTest)
{
  $additionalTestCost = current($additionalTestCostsSelected);

  $additionalTestsSelected[] = array(
    'id' => $availableTest->getID(),
    'name' => $availableTest->getName(),
    'cost' => $additionalTestCost->getFormattedCost()
  );

  next($additionalTestCostsSelected);
}

$appointment = $this->getAppointment();

$tokens = array(
  '%DATE%' => $this->getAppointment()->getDate(),
  '%LOCATION%' => $this->getAppointment()->getLocation(),
  '%TIME%' => $this->getTime(),
  '%ROOM%' => $this->getRoom(),
  '%NAME%' => ($this->getUser() ? $this->getUser()->getFullName() : null),
  '%TZ%'   => $this->getAppointment()->getShowTimeZone() ? $this->getAppointment()->getTimeZone() : '',
  '%AdditionalTestsSelected%' => $availableTest->getName(),
);

return str_replace(array_keys($tokens), array_values($tokens), $emailContents);
}
```

I want to get the value of $availableTest->getName() and put it into array $tokens. What is the right way to do that?

```
$additionalTestsSelected = array();

foreach($additionalTests as $availableTest)
{
  //$additionalTestConfirmation[] = $availableTest->getName();

}

$appointment = $this->getAppointment();

$tokens = array(
    '%DATE%' => $this->getAppointment()->getDate(),
    '%LOCATION%' => $this->getAppointment()->getLocation(),
    '%TIME%' => $this->getTime(),
    '%ROOM%' => $this->getRoom(),
    '%NAME%' => ($this->getUser() ? $this->getUser()->getFullName() : null),
    '%TZ%'   => $this->getAppointment()->getShowTimeZone() ? $this->getAppointment()->getTimeZone() : '',
    '%AdditionalTestsSelected%' => $availableTest->getName(),
  );
```

Comment: Fix your indentation, then you'll be able to see scope problems more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

`$availableTest` is out of scope in that line.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do there...

Comment: I just want to get the value of $availableTest->getName() and put it into array $tokens. What is the right way to do that?

Comment: Which `$availableTest`?  That variable is from the `for` loop, and changes on each iteration.  Use `$additionalTests['key']` to get the value you want.

Comment: out of scope = the variable doesn't exist anymore there. from the naming it looks like you want to put `$additionalTestsSelected` into the array

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the value of $availableTest->getName() and put it into array $tokens. What is the right way to do that?

$availableTest represents one object out of the $additionalTests array. It only exists within the scope of the foreach block. The question is, which object out of the $additionalTests do you want the name of?

If you want AdditionalTestsSelected to represent a string of all the names, create a new array for just the names before the foreach loop. With each iteration of the loop, assign the name to your new $names array. At this point, use the PHP function implode() to return a string of your array (comma delimited, or however you want it). Pass this new string in to your associative array $tokens where you are currently passing in $availableTest->getName().

Comment: thanks so much for your reply. I tried what you said and get this error message:  Notice: Array to string conversion in /Users/alexhu/NetBeansProjects/menagerie/svn/trunk/apps/frontend/modules/legacy/legacy_lib/lib/classes/AppointmentTime.php on line 383

Comment: What I want to do is to get the value of $availableTest->getName(). It is the specific value for each user. So if I just output the whole values to an array, I am not sure if I can get the value I want that way

Comment: Could you post the exact code you are trying to run, that produces this error? For a short term fix, or perhaps a better solution, instead of using an array use a string and append new names to the end of it. `$names .= ", " . $availableTest->getName();` within the `foreach` block. Then you simply have a string instead of an array to deal with.

Comment: My last reply was to your first reply, I didn't see your second comment; sorry for any confusion. `AdditionalTestsSelected` to me, indicates you are looking for one or more values. If you are looking for a specific value from within the array, you'll need to know what index that value has (0, 1, 2,.. 99, etc.). If you know what value and index you are looking for, simply call it with `$additionalTests[$index]->getName();`. For clarity, `$index` will need to be created and initiated with the index you are looking for.

Comment: Akaishen, I appreciate your help. I don't know which index I am looking for. But when I have the following codes, I can get the right value except a system error "Undefined variable"

Comment: Due to there is no enough space for the comment. I put the code in the end of my topic

Comment: @Alex Hu: You don't even know what you want to do there? Then how should we be able to anwer your question? It's like asking "hey I want to divide by zero, how can I do that?". What should I answer to that?

Comment: I think the problem here is we don't know exactly what you are trying to do and the code you are providing isn't specific enough to help. Only provide what's necessary to answer your specific question. Your original question has to do with variable scope. Perhaps reading [php scope documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) will help you understand scope.